# Purpose of using autotrack.js in applications

Tags: javascript

what is the use of `autotrack.js`..

I came this js file when viewing source in below link.

view-source:http://elgoog.im/underwater/

Comment: It's a google analytics thing... And completely unrelated to C#.

Comment: Can we use this in our applications for analytics report ?